# QML combobox popup out of the window bounds

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am creating a custom `ComboBox` in QML and need the popup to be able to extend beyond the window borders.

[image: desired]

I'm using `QtQuick.Controls.Universal` to customize it. However, when I implement it, the parent `Window` clips the `Popup`. I tried using `Menu` instead, but that didn't work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
popup: Controls.Popup {
  y: root.height
  width: root.width
  implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
  padding: 0
  closePolicy: Controls.Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent

  contentItem: ListView {
    id: itemsView
    z: 1
    implicitHeight: contentHeight
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    model: root.popup.visible ? root.delegateModel : null
    currentIndex: root.highlightedIndex
  }
  
  background: Item { }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

[image]

How can I prevent the `Popup` from being clipped by the parent `Window`? One solution I've found is to replace `Popup` with `Window`, but that would require me to set the `x` and `y` values manually, which I'm trying to avoid. I want the `Window` (`Popup`, `Menu`, etc) to be positioned directly below the `ComboBox`.

Additional information:

- Qt 6.5.1
- Windows 11

Comment: If the parent of the combobox is an actual `Window`, I don't think you can draw outside of it. Using another Window for your popup might be the only way.